# DynamoDB Key Design

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with the following keys:

PKey (Partition Key)
SKey (Sort Key)

[image]

I want to store holidays for a range of countries, and answer the following 2 questions:

- give me all holidays in 2020 between a range of months
- give me all holidays in 2020 between a range of months for a specific country

Currently the PKey holds the year and the SKey the month and day (12-31).  I've added Country (ISO) to the SKey, however I can't answer both questions.  Is there another design that would work?  I'm trying to avoid a GSI.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a Local Secondary Index (LSI) instead of the GSI?  There's no extra cost associated with a LSI.

You could have the table sort key be "County"-"Month"-"Day"

Then your second access requirement could be serviced by

```
Query(pkey = "2020", skey between "GB-10-01" and "GB-12-31")
```

Then you LSI sort key would just be "Month"-"Day" and could service your first access requirement.

```
Query(index='MYLSI', pkey = "2020", skey between "10-01" and "12-31")
```